# Displaying virtual keyboard when needed

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

There is an option called `SearchPane.ShowOnKeyboardInput` which displays the `Search Charm` when the user starts typing.

My problem is that if the user runs my app on `Surface` tablet, with no keyboard attached, there is no keyboard for the user to "start typing".

I tried displaying the `Search Charm` at the very beginning but this leads to unexpected results sometimes. The windows displays the virtual (On-Screen keyboard) just **sometimes**.

What is the best way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Not sure I understand, so on device w/o keyboard, wouldn't user swipe to get to Search, then the on-screen keyboard would naturally appear?  IOW, non-keyboard users have to do an additional gesture, but that's somewhat expected isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's what expected. But that's not what really happens :(
Actually, when the Search charm appears, the virtual keyboard does NOT pop up __all the time__. Windows only shows the keyboard sometimes (yes, it seems like a bug to me either). However, I was wondering if there is any solution for __making sure__ that the user gets a virtual keyboard, if a physical one is not available.